# Pass char* to pthread_read function

Tags: c++, linux, char, pthreads, void-pointers

I'm trying to create a pthread and insert it on a list for every line that I read in file.txt.

I try to send a char* to the function showMessage in pthread_create, but when I try to print it, I get a blank space on the screen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

using namespace std;

void *showMessage( void *ptr ){

   cout << "String: " << (char*)ptr << endl; //Blank space

    pthread_exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{  
    list<pthread_t*>thrds;
    list<pthread_t*>::iterator it;
    pthread_t * pt;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t read;
    char * line = NULL;
    FILE * fp;
    int iret;

    fp = fopen ("./file.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
      fclose (fp);
      return 1;
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {   //Read file.txt
        pt = new pthread_t();
        thrds.push_back(pt);
        iret = pthread_create( pt, NULL, showMessage, line); //Create pthread and send function ShowMessage and line read in file.txt
        if(iret)
        {   
           fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (list<pthread_t*>::iterator it = thrds.begin(); it != thrds.end(); ++it){
         pthread_join( **it, NULL);   
    }

    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  Particularly, try eliminating the threads to see if the problem goes away and make the problem as simple as possible with it still being compilable and still with the bug.

Comment: Since you're using C++, why not use `std::string` and `std::thread` instead of raw `char*`s and pthreads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour because at the same time you are writing and reading the same buffer of memory, look:

```
iret = pthread_create( pt, NULL, showMessage, line); // start reading operation
```

above line starts the thread which prints characters pointed by `line` pointer.  After this thread started in next iteration of while loop you call `getline` function which gets `line` by-pointer. `getline` may modify string pointed by `line` at the same time when it is printed in started thread.

After reading line you could make a copy then pass this copy to print function.

```
    pt = new pthread_t();
    thrds.push_back(pt);
    char* copy = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
    strcpy(copy,line);
    iret = pthread_create( pt, NULL, showMessage, copy); // <-
```

now, writing and reading operations are separated and it should work. Remember to free all allocated resources.

Comment: I believe that the line buffer is declared as a char*, and that memory is never allocated.  Hence, it would be necessary to also add a line to allocate stack space for the initial line buffer. e.g. `char line_buffer[1000]; char* line = line_buffer;` or something similar up higher.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++, it would be much easier to use `std::thread` and `std::string` instead of pthreads and raw `char*`s.  Not only is `std::thread` much easier to use with C++ objects, it's cross-platform as well.

Using the standard C++ constructs, your program would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

void showMessage(const std::string& str) {
   std::cout << "String: " << str << '\n';
}

int main() {  
    std::list<std::thread> thrds;

    std::ifstream file("file.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {   //Read file.txt
        thrds.emplace_back(showMessage, std::move(line)); // Create thread and add it to the list
    }

    for (std::thread& th : thrds) {
         th.join();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d96ec734fbb85c9)